# Display pdf within android app with revise option

Tags: android, eclipse, pdf, revision, pdfviewer

I want to display pdfs in an android application when some buttons are clicked. And i want to revise those pdfs weekly for maintenance purposes (alike we do in google drive). As I don't want users to download new apk for a new pdf.

Currently I am displaying pdfs using google drive. But users are not comfortable with opening up webpage for each pdfs.

Is there any way to **display pdf within android application** when a button is clicked and with an **option to manage it's revisions**?

Questions: 1. If i could revise it, where should i store the new pdf or how do i need to manage pdfs.

Please help. I am unable to find its answer. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting ready to try this.  I read through it and it seems as if it may meet your needs, if I understand you correctly.

https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js

Please note, this is going to require some adaptation on your part.